# Прогресбар в MVC

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mvc, progress-bar

Появилась необходимость сделать прелоадер. Движок построен на MVC. Нашел скрипт никак не могу его внедрить в свой проект вот html:

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="person">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <h3 id="status"></h3>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
  var file = _("file1").files[0];
  // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
  var formdata = new FormData(document.forms.person);
  formdata.append("file1", file);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "../index.php");
  ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
  _("progressBar").value = 0;
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
```

И серверная часть:

```
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "image/$fileName")){
    echo "$fileName upload is complete";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
```

Как реализовать этот скрипт через MVC

Comment: Вместо index.php обращайтесь к роуту, а там контроллер.

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо все заработало